# Need to run Lucene Analyzer offline from servlet

Tags: java, lucene

This might be quite a meaty question but my problem is that I have a Spring servlet that is used for real-time searching.  I need to strip out the Lucene analyzer so that it runs offline and is called by the servlet everytime a query comes in to it, rather than having the analyzer within the servlet.  However, I don't quite know how to do this, and call the analyzer service from the servlet.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

At the moment, I have this:

```
RAMDirectory ramDirectory = new RAMDirectory();
StandardAnalyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Version.LUCENE_31);

IndexWriterConfig config = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LUCENE_31, analyzer);
IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(ramDirectory, config);
Document document = new Document();

// TEST DATA
document.add(new Field("firstName", "John", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
document.add(new Field("occupation", "Engineer", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));

document.add(new Field("firstName", "Mary", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
document.add(new Field("occupation", "Field Engineer", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));

document.add(new Field("firstName", "Jamie", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
document.add(new Field("occupation", "Primary teacher", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
// END TEST DATA

indexWriter.addDocument(document);
indexWriter.optimize();
indexWriter.close();

IndexSearcher indexSearcher = new IndexSearcher(ramDirectory);
String[] fields = {"firstName", "occupation"};
MultiFieldQueryParser parser = new MultiFieldQueryParser(null, fields, analyzer);
Query query = parser.parse(searchQuery);

// Parsing of results here
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify: do you want to run Lucene as a separate process that listens on some socket and call it from your servlet, or would you like to launch LuceneAnalyzer on-demand as a new process from your servlet?

Comment: Hi, sorry, I want it to run as a separate process.

Comment: Making sure I got the workflow you're looking for right: (1) servlet receives http request (2) offloads processing to a separate lucene process (3) get results from lucene (4) respond to user. Is that the general idea?

Comment: Yep, that's exactly it.  I've got it working all within the servlet, but I realise this is poor design in terms of performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you find your current design poor in terms of performance? What problem are you running into exactly?

I believe that what you're looking for is some form of inter-process communications. Two options that come to mind are:

1. Synchronous: offload processing to another server (HTTP or plain TCP) that envelopes Lucene and responds with the query results.
   This will be useful for scaling your system since it lets you easily separate Lucene to another machine, but other than that, there are no immediate performance gains.
2. Asynchronous: offload it to a queue (e.g. ZeroMQ) that some other process listens on, runs Lucene, then returns the result through some other queue. 
   This is less advantageous if you need to respond to a user on the other end, and in any case will be hard to implement with java servlets (though if anyone knows otherwise, I'd love to hear about it).